# Why are the results of 'print(a, b, c, sep=' ')' and 'print(a, '\t', b, '\t', c)' different?

Tags: python, printing, tabs

Result of this line: `print(gid, size, num_A, num_C, num_G, num_T, pc_GC, not_ACTG, sep="\t")`
print out the following result:

```
chrI    230218  69836   44640   45765   69974   0.39    3
chrII   813184  249672  157392  154391  251728  0.38    1
chrIII  316620  98656   62358   59642   95963   0.39    1
chrIV   1531943 476761  289337  291364  474471  0.38    10
chrIX   439888  134339  85465   85661   134423  0.39    0
chrM    85779   36169   6863    7813    34934   0.17    0
chrV    576874  176533  109826  112313  178202  0.39    0
chrVI   270161  82936   52197   52433   82595   0.39    0
chrVII  1090940 338308  207771  207456  337405  0.38    0
chrVIII 562643  174024  109103  107487  172029  0.38    0
chrX    745751  231169  142294  143875  228413  0.38    0
chrXI   666816  206161  127768  126085  206802  0.38    0
chrXII  1078177 330584  207777  207066  332750  0.38    0
chrXIII 924431  286298  176734  176432  284967  0.38    0
chrXIV  784333  241558  151659  151391  239725  0.39    0
chrXV   1091291 339394  209023  207416  335458  0.38    0
```

In contrast, result of this line: `print(gid, "\t", size, "\t", num_A, "\t", num_C, "\t", num_G, "\t", num_T, "\t", pc_GC, "\t", not_ACTG)`
print out the following result:

```
chrI     230218          69836   44640   45765   69974   0.39    3
chrII    813184          249672          157392          154391          251728          0.38    1
chrIII   316620          98656   62358   59642   95963   0.39    1
chrIV    1531943         476761          289337          291364          474471          0.38    10
chrIX    439888          134339          85465   85661   134423          0.39    0
chrM     85779   36169   6863    7813    34934   0.17    0
chrV     576874          176533          109826          112313          178202          0.39    0
chrVI    270161          82936   52197   52433   82595   0.39    0
chrVII   1090940         338308          207771          207456          337405          0.38    0
chrVIII          562643          174024          109103          107487          172029          0.38  0
chrX     745751          231169          142294          143875          228413          0.38    0
chrXI    666816          206161          127768          126085          206802          0.38    0
chrXII   1078177         330584          207777          207066          332750          0.38    0
chrXIII          924431          286298          176734          176432          284967          0.38  0
chrXIV   784333          241558          151659          151391          239725          0.39    0
chrXV    1091291         339394          209023          207416          335458          0.38    0
```

I was expecting them to be identical. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

They are not the same because the default `sep` for [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is `' '` (i.e. a single space), not an empty string as you seem to expect. The separator is printed between every two adjacent arguments, so calling `print(a, "\t")` without setting `sep` will print the value of `a`, a space, and then a tab character. This extra space messes up the formatting.